# Question about an inequation described by matrices.

Tags: analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

$A=(a_{ij})_{1 \le i, j \le n}$ is a matrix that$\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n} a_{ij}=1$ for every j and $\sum_\limits{j=1}^n a_{ij} = 1$ for every i and $a_{ij} \ge 0$.And
$$\begin{equation}
  \begin{pmatrix}
  y_1 \\
  \vdots \\
  y_n \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  =\mathbf{A}
  \begin{pmatrix}
  x_1 \\
  \vdots \\
  x_n
  \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation}$$
$y_i$ and $x_i$ are all nonnegative.Prove that : $y_1 \cdots y_n \ge x_1 \cdots x_n$

It may somehow matter to convex function.

Comment: can you write out the inequality fully? That is, replace each $y_i$ with its expression in terms of the $x_i$'s

Comment: @mathworker21 i have written it out fully but it doesn't help. Or you means to edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: just write it out fully in the question. i don't have paper on me

Comment: @mathworker21 $ \prod_\limits{i=1}^{n} (\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}x_j) = \prod_\limits{j=1}^{n} x_j $

Comment: ok, so the LHS has the terms $(\prod_{j=1}^n a_{f(j)j})\prod_{j=1}^n x_j$, for any $f: \{1,\dots,n\} \to \{1,\dots,n\}$. Now just add all of these terms up. You should get $\prod_{j=1}^n x_j$, right?

Comment: The reason is that $\sum_f (\prod_{j=1}^n a_{f(j)j}) = \prod_{j=1}^n (a_{1j}+a_{2j}+\dots+a_{nj}) = \prod_{j=1}^n 1 = 1$.

Comment: sorry i need to revise $ \prod_\limits{i=1}^{n} (\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}x_j) \ge \prod_\limits{j=1}^{n} x_j $

Comment: I think my two comments give a proof that $y_1\dots y_n \ge x_1 \dots x_n$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I don't think $\sum_f(\prod_{j=1}^n a_{f(j)j})=\prod_{j=1}^n(a_{1j}+\cdots +a_{nj})$. Consider $n=2$ then $a_{11}a_{22}+a_{21}a_{12} \neq (a_{11}+a_{21})(a_{12}+a_{22})$

Comment: any $f$, not just bijective $f$

Comment: @mathworker21 then some term $(\prod_{j=1}^n a_{f(j)j})\prod_{j=1}^n x_j$ doesn't exist. For example, let $f(i) =1$ for all $i$, and there is no term $(a_{11}\cdots a_{1n})(x_1\cdots x_n)$ since all $a_{1i}x_i$ are in the same bracket.

Comment: Posted also on MathOverflow: [Question about an inequation described by matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/q/319474). In my opinion, [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives a very reasonable advice about [cross-posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-posting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:
If any $y_i$ is zero, from the condition on $a_{ij}$, at least one $x_k$ must be zero, so we may consider only positive $x_i,y_j$. Also the doubly stochastic matrix represents the majorization $x \succ y$, so by Karamata’s Inequality, with the concave $\log$ function,  $\sum \log y_i \geqslant \sum \log x_i$.